# Moving ten files at a time using Vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, file, directory, move

I as seeking to move 10 file every 10 minutes from one folder to another using .NET (vb c#)
I am was thinking that i could of achieve this with LINQ query, but i cant get my head around this - 
would there be a solution with LINQ or otherwise 
that can select the last 10 files form or top 10 files. so that i can move only these files from Directory1 ( the big pool of files) into director 2 ( a smaller more manageable pool of files).
If all fails- then i wll manually have to copy or cut to at a time.
Regards
thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this:

```
For Each fileName As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath).Take(10)
  File.Move(fileName, newFolder)
Next
```